# Rails: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when setting first address created as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csrf, csrf-token, actioncontroller

I'm encountering an issue in my Rails application where I get ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when trying to set the first address as default. The error occurs during the create action in the AddressesController. I've tried various solutions such as adding protect_from_forgery and csrf_meta_tags, but the problem persists. The strange thing is that this issue only happens with the first address created, and subsequent addresses work fine and I can set them as default addresses. I've provided my controller code and relevant views for reference.

I've tried adding protect_from_forgery with: :exception, including csrf_meta_tags in my layout, and ensuring the form_authenticity_token is present in my forms. I expected these measures to resolve the ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken issue, but it still persists, specifically when attempting to set the first address as default. Other addresses don't trigger this error.

```
def set_default
    @address = current_user.addresses.find(params[:id])

    current_user.addresses.update_all(default: false)
    if @address.update(default: true)
      flash[:notice] = "Default address set successfully."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Failed to set default address. Errors: #{address.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
    end

    redirect_to user_addresses_path(current_user)
end
```

```
<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
        <% unless address.default %>
          <div>
            <%= form_tag set_default_user_address_path(@user, address), method: :post do %>
              <div>
                <%= address.first_name %> <%= address.last_name %> <br>
                <%= address.street %><br>
                <%= address.city %><br>
                <%= address.county %><br>
                <%= address.postcode %><br>
                <%= address.phone_number %>
              </div>
              <br><br>
              <%= submit_tag 'Set as Default', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
              <br><br>
            <% end %>
            <%= button_to "Delete", user_address_path(@user, address), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this address?" }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
            <br><br>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

UPDATE

I added protect_from_forgery with: :null_session to the addresses_controller and the initial CSRF error has gone. Now I have this error =>

ActionController::ParameterMissing in AddressesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: address
Extracted source (around line #66):
64
65
66
67
68

def address_params
params.require(:address).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :street, :city, :county, :postcode, :phone_number)
end
end

But the address_params are part of the create method, not set_default method. So I'm not sure whats going on here.

I inspected the HTML using the inspector tools, the first address is not showing to be within form tags. All other address are however. Very strange. Any help will be appreciated.